# C++ template's template failed to compile

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, constants

I've got this test program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template<template<class> class C, typename T>
void print(const C<T>& c){
    for(auto& e : c)cout<<e<<endl;
}
int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    print(v);
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile:

```
g++ m.cpp -std=c++11
m.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
m.cpp:11:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(std::vector<int>&)’
        print(v);
                ^
m.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<template<class> class C, class T> void print(const C<T>&)
void print(const C<T>& c){
    ^~~~~
m.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
m.cpp:11:16: note:   template parameters of a template template argument are inconsistent with other deduced template arguments
        print(v);
                ^
```

I changed print() signature from (const C& c) to (C& c), it still fails:

```
$ g++ m.cpp -std=c++11
m.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
m.cpp:11:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(std::vector<int>&)’
        print(v);
                ^
m.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<template<class> class C, class T> void print(C<T>&)
void print(C<T>& c){
    ^~~~~
m.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
m.cpp:11:16: note:   template parameters of a template template argument are inconsistent with other deduced template arguments
        print(v);
                ^
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You don't need the extra `template<class>` specification there, `vector<int>` is already fully specified and sufficient.

Comment: Not a dupe as it doesn't explain the issue at hand.

Comment: OP, the problem is that `std::vector<T>` is in fact `std::vector<T,A>`.

Comment: This problem can easily be worked around by simply using `template<class T>`. There is no benefit to using a template template parameter here.

Comment: If you decide to reopen my dupe closures, please consider to write an answer that solves the problem specifically. IMO the duplicate was good enough to answer that specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compilation problem arises because your [*template template parameter*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) `C` doesn't match the declaration of `std::vector`:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

As you can see, **`std::vector` has two template parameters, while your `C` has only one.** But, note as well that the second parameter (`class Allocator`) has a *default* type argument. Since C++17, this is well-formed even the way you've written it, as it was added that *template template parameters* matching doesn't require specifying parameters for ones with default arguments like `Allocator`. But not all compilers are supporting this modification to the language spec -- see [here live how Clang 6.0.0 refuses](https://godbolt.org/z/S6fMW9) to compile your original snippet with C++17 enabled. Going for older versions of C++ (or just any version to date of Clang), this snippet is probably what you were aiming for:

```
template<template<class, class> class C, typename T, typename A>
void print(const C<T, A>& c){
    for(auto& e : c)cout<<e<<endl;
}
```

As here you specify the correct template signature of the type (`std::vector`) you're later instantiating `print()` with.

---

This would work too, regardless of C++17:

```
template<template<class...> class C, typename T>
void print(const C<T>& c){
    for(auto& e : c)cout<<e<<endl;
}
```

---

That said, note that, as `vector<int>` is already a fully instantiated type, **this simpler version works just as well** in the given scope of your snippet:

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T& c){
    for(auto& e : c)cout<<e<<endl;
}
```

---

> I changed print() signature from `(const C& c)` to `(C& c)`, it still
>   fails:

This is probably the better practice in this case, as you're not modifying `c` inside of `print()`. However, this has nothing to do with your error.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) contains two template parameters, while the template template parameter `C` is declared to contain only one. Anyway, your code would work fine with C++17; since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)), the default template arguments are allowed for a [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DAu9ToxS7Qfui3MW)

Before C++17 you may apply [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```
template<template<class...> class C, typename T>
void print(const C<T>& c){
    for(auto& e : c)cout<<e<<endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KFS184RMCBDhfy5s)

Comment: First version fails on Clang 6.0.0 with C++17 for some reason

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist The head version ([clang 8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kPQ1NR1eHBJUEWpZ)) with `c++2a` mode doesn't work either. It seems clang have not supported the feature.